# Can I damage my IPhone by overcharging

Tags: charging, iphone

Can I damage my iPhone 5c if I charge it when the battery is fully charged? I use the charger from Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can damage your Iphone 5c if you charge it when it is already full BUT, the iphone 5c (and all iphones)  has built in battery management system that will not allow the battery to be charged once it is full.

So if you plug it in and try to charge it when it is full, the battery protection will kick in and prevent any charging from ocurring.  So you have nothing to worry about.  However, despite the battery protection system, they still recommend that you unplug your phone after it has been charged.

Comment: You said "_... they still recommend ..._", well just who is "_they_"? If you have an authoritative source then post the URL to the authoritative document.

Comment: "Yes you can damage" and "you have nothing to worry about" contradict each other somehow. Can you please clarify your answer?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot overcharge it because careful account is made of the charge in the cells by internal circuitry which will not charge the battery when it is fully charged. Many of the technologies involved in modern, power dense batteries react very badly indeed to overcharging, so much so that a little circuit, usually built into the battery itself, acts as a kind of charge "accountant" to ensure it's impossible for things to get out-of-hand.